# Passing array from POSTMAN and AJAX is different when received by ExpressJS

Tags: ajax, express

I am new to Express but not in programming. I am trying to pass an array via ajax from my frontend to express. On my postman, this is the array I am sending:

```
{
    "userIds": ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
    "type": "user"
}
```

and express is receiving req.body as:

```
{
  userIds: [ 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ],
  type: 'user'
}
```

When I do this in Ajax:

```
data = {
    userIds: ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
    type: "user",
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    headers: headerParams,
    data: data,
    success: function (room) {
        console.log("room", room);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    },
});
```

Express is receiving:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
    'userIds[]': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    type: 'user'
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or how should I mutate my req.body to get the desired output?

Note: I cannot do req.body.Foreach since it is saying forEach is not a function.

Note 2: req.body.userIds returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

My best guess, Middleware [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to your rescue.

You can then access it as `req.body.userIds`, which will be an Array.